# Wordpress uploads autocreate folder every month

Tags: uploads, media

In start of every month WP creating folder with month number, like /uploads/2019/11, and it's creating with ROOT, so I dont have permission to write it. If I delete it, and then it's creating when I uploading smth - it's ok.
So problem only in this AUTOCREATE folder every 1st day of month. How can I disable it? I cant configure server. So I need to disable this autocreating every month and leave the folder was created only with the media file upload.

Comment: This is not default WordPress behavior. Try contacting your host, if they can give you more insight into this. I doubt a plugin or theme is responsible, since they should not be able to create folders as root on the server (or if they were, you should also be able to write to those directories).

Comment: If it's being done automatically every months you could look into what cron jobs are being excecuted every x day of the month.

Answer (score 1):

Coming back to this question after I encountered the same problem. There is at least one WordPress core cron that creates the month folders: `wp_privacy_delete_old_export_files`.

So if the WP Cron is run a root user, the folder will be created by root as well and not be accessible to the webserver user. Solution is to run the cron as webserver user as well.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you was right, problem was in cron from root user. Dont know why, but folders creating even if nothing upload there, only if smth use wp scripts